# Masterializecss make background-color 100% of window when using container

Tags: css

I am using materializecss in my landing page. I have the page set up in a container (with the `html {background-color: yellow}`, but I want my background color in the second div to extend the full width of the window. How can I "extend past the bounds of the container"

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty0o7e83/1/)

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="theme-landingpage-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m12 l12 s12 layout-header">
        <p class="headertitle">MELLOW<br /> MOMENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row layout-hero">
      <div class="col s12 m6 l6 module-hero-picture-badge">
        <img id="badge" src="app/assets/img/login/badge.png" alt="">
        <img id="boxhero" src="app/assets/img/login/boxhero.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l6 module-hero-text">
        <img id="text-chill-banner" src="app/assets/img/login/banner.png" alt="">
        <img id="talking-to-you" src="app/assets/img/login/text-talking-to-you.png" alt="">
        <p>Take your life back. Breathe. Take stock of yourself. You need a break. Take one.<br>
          Focus your mind. Relax your body.<br>
          <p style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important; font-weight: 400 !important; font-style: italic;">(and Take a Toke).</p>
        </p>
        <img id="text-retake-moment" src="app/assets/img/login/moment-text.png" alt="">
        <img class="shop-button" src="app/assets/img/login/shopbut.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.theme-landingpage-main {
  background-color: #FFD000;

  //layouts and modules for landing page '/login'
  .layout-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #FFD000;
    .headertitle {
      font-size: 40px !important;
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'Lobster Two', sans-serif !important;
      font-weight: 400;
      bottom: 25px;
    }
  }

  .layout-hero { <---------------- this is the div in question
    background-color: #F2F2F2; 
    .module-hero-picture-badge {
      #badge {
        position: relative;
        width: 65%;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      #boxhero {
        width: 75%;
        position: relative;
        left: 17%;
        bottom: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
    .module-hero-text{
      p {
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        right: 23px;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #text-chill-banner {
        width: 128%;
        position: relative;
        right: 20%;
        top: 50px;
        z-index: 3;
      }
      #talking-to-you {
        width: 480px;
        position: relative;
        top: 41px;
        right: 45px;
      }
      #text-retake-moment {
        width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        right: 12%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is close the initial `.container` (holding the logo) open a new div with a custom class enabling you to style it up (give it white background), open a new `.container` and have your hero content. When done, close `.container` again, close `.white-bg`, re-open `.container` and continue page.

```css
.white-bg {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme-landingpage-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m12 l12 s12 layout-header">
        <p class="headertitle">MELLOW<br /> MOMENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- closed container -->
  <div class="white-bg"> <!-- full width -->
    <div class="container"> <!-- new container -->
      <div class="row layout-hero">
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6 module-hero-picture-badge">
          <img id="badge" src="app/assets/img/login/badge.png" alt="">
          <img id="boxhero" src="app/assets/img/login/boxhero.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6 module-hero-text">
          <img id="text-chill-banner" src="app/assets/img/login/banner.png" alt="">
          <img id="talking-to-you" src="app/assets/img/login/text-talking-to-you.png" alt="">
          <p>Take your life back. Breathe. Take stock of yourself. You need a break. Take one.<br>
            Focus your mind. Relax your body.<br></p>
          <p style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important; font-weight: 400 !important; font-style: italic;">(and Take a Toke).</p>
          <img id="text-retake-moment" src="app/assets/img/login/moment-text.png" alt="">
          <img class="shop-button" src="app/assets/img/login/shopbut.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- closed container -->
  </div> <!-- closed white-bg -->
  <div class="container">
    Some other content, in container...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Side note:** I noticed you have nested `<p>` tags. That's invalid `HTML` and will cause rendering problems. Most browsers will close the initial `<p>` tag before opening a new one, leaving your ending `</p>` orphan. Sometimes this doesn't have any visible effects, but it has the potential to break page or cause *bugs* that are hard to track/fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using container for separate `div`

**HTML**

```
<div class="theme-landingpage-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m12 l12 s12 layout-header">
         <p class="headertitle">MELLOW<br /> MOMENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="theme-landingpage-main white">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="row layout-hero">
         <div class="col s12 m12 l12 module-hero-picture-badge">
       </div>
       <div class="col s12 m12 l12 module-hero-text">
        <p>Take your life back. Breathe. Take stock of yourself. Take one.<br>
      Focus your mind. Relax your body.<br>
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Add class white or `background-color: #fff`  of this `div` class

```
.white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/pRqgQZ)

Answer (score 0):

As per Grid explained in Materialize documentation. "It allows you to center your page content. The container class is set to ~70% of the window width. It helps you center and contain your page content. We use the container to contain our body content."

You need to divide the `.container` class withing the page. Where you want full width, just exclude that area from `.container`.

Example:

```
<div class="yellowBkg">
   <header class="container">
      Header Content
   </header>
   <div class="fullWidthGrayBkg">
      <div class="container">
        Because you need content within container.
      </div>
   <div>
   <div class="container">
       Further Content.
   </div>
</div>
```

See your fiddle modified with solution: https://jsfiddle.net/avtarnanrey/ugr9qjp7/1/